# ionic 1 modules are not available for android build once the minSdkVersion set to 22

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

**Before everything**: ionic serve works as expected and the problem occurs only when the project is built for android.

I have an ionic 1 android application currently in Google Playstore, and recently wanted to update the app and release in the playstore. When submitting a new apk I got the prompt by playstore that my current app is using a minimum supported api which is 19 and needs to be updated to 22 to be released.
So i have changed the config.xml minSdkVersion from 19 to 22 (refer below for the code) and after that I started to get the following errors in my application when running the app on the emulator or device, take note that the build is successful (refer to the screenshot).

Before:
`<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />`

Now:
`<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="22" />`

[image]

I have tried to research the problem and saw a suggestion to add the following line (refer below) into config.xml as well, but nothing changed.

`<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />`

I also tried to start a completely new blank project on ionic 1 and build to apk to eliminate any issues with development setup and it builds and works as expected

I assume that the issue is that my project does not build properly based on the errors I receive however I am not able to find the exact cause. All the relevant files are attached, hope for any input to eliminate the errors that prompt during the build

my `config.xml`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="test.test.test.test" version="1.1.7" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <name>test</name>
    <description>
        test
    </description>
    <author email="test" href="http://example.com.com/">
      test
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="22" />
    <preferance name="android-usesCleartextTraffic" value="true" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="4500" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="750" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <feature name="StatusBar">
        <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="CDVStatusBar" />
    </feature>
    <platform name="android">
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000" />
        <resource-file src="google-services.json" target="app/google-services.json" />
    </platform>
    <icon src="resources\android\icon\drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://quotes.wsj.com/" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="data:*" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="^1.0.7" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="2.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-facebook" spec="^0.2.2">
        <variable name="FACEBOOK_DISPLAY_NAME" value="test" />
        <variable name="FACEBOOK_APP_ID" value="test" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="^1.7.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^4.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="^2.2.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^4.0.0" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://192.168.0.116:8100" />
    <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
    </edit-config>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-toast" spec="^2.7.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-admob-free" spec="^0.27.0">
        <variable name="ADMOB_APP_ID" value="test" />
    </plugin>
</widget>
```

my `package.json`

```
"name": "test",
    "version": "1.1.1",
    "description": "test",
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^5.2.8",
        "bower": "^1.8.8",
        "cordova-admob-sdk": "^0.24.1",
        "cordova-browser": "^6.0.0",
        "cordova-plugin-admob-free": "^0.27.0",
        "cordova-plugin-androidx": "^2.0.0",
        "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": "^1.1.1",
        "cordova-plugin-console": "^1.1.0",
        "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.7",
        "cordova-plugin-enable-multidex": "^0.2.0",
        "cordova-plugin-facebook": "^0.2.2",
        "cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics": "^4.3.0",
        "cordova-plugin-firebase-dynamiclinks": "^4.4.0",
        "cordova-plugin-firebasex": "^9.1.2-cli",
        "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^1.7.2",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.1.0",
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4",
        "cordova-plugin-x-toast": "^2.7.2",
        "cordova-promise-polyfill": "0.0.2",
        "cordova-support-android-plugin": "^1.0.2",
        "cordova-support-google-services": "1.4.0",
        "gulp": "^3.5.6",
        "gulp-clean-css": "^4.3.0",
        "gulp-concat": "^2.2.0",
        "gulp-rename": "^1.2.0",
        "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0",
        "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
        "ng-cordova-oauth": "^0.3.0",
        "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
        "shelljs": "^0.8.3"
    },
    "platforms": [
        "android"
    ],
    "cordova": {
        "platforms": [
            "browser",
            "android"
        ],
        "plugins": {
            "cordova-plugin-console": {},
            "cordova-plugin-device": {},
            "cordova-plugin-facebook": {
                "FACEBOOK_DISPLAY_NAME": "test",
                "FACEBOOK_APP_ID": "test"
            },
            "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
            "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
            "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
            "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
            "cordova-plugin-x-toast": {},
            "cordova-plugin-admob-free": {
                "ADMOB_APP_ID": "test"
            },
            "cordova-support-google-services": {},
            "cordova-plugin-firebasex": {
                "FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_COLLECTION_ENABLED": "true",
                "FIREBASE_PERFORMANCE_COLLECTION_ENABLED": "true",
                "FIREBASE_CRASHLYTICS_COLLECTION_ENABLED": "true"
            },
            "cordova-plugin-enable-multidex": {},
            "cordova-plugin-firebase-dynamiclinks": {
                "PAGE_LINK_DOMAIN": "vindexscreener.page.link",
                "FIREBASE_DYNAMIC_LINKS_VERSION": "19.1.+"
            },
            "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
                "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
            }
        }
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@ionic/v1-toolkit": "2.0.17",
        "cordova-android": "^9.0.0",
        "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.2.1",
        "ionic": "5.4.16"
    }
}
```